# What happens to my Darkmoon Blade spell if I kill Gwyndolin?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm getting to rank 3 in the Darkmoon covenant. And I heard that each rank after you get the Darkmoon Blade buffs the spell, making it a 1.0, 2.0, etc. So will I lose the buffs that I got from my rank if I kill her/him?

Answer (score 2):

You will not only lose the buff if you kill Gwyndolin, but you will also be unable to cast Darkmoon Blade at all if you do so, because you can only cast the spell as long as you are a member of the Darkmoon. Killing Gwyndolin breaks the covenant and makes using the spell impossible.

Since Gwyndolin is the convenant leader, you won't be able to rejoin the covenant until NG+. According to [the wiki](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/blade-of-the-darkmoon), leaving or betraying the covenant also leads to the count of your Souvenir of Reprisal offerings being halved, so you would also probably lose a rank in the covenant if you rejoin in a later playthrough.

Comment: @Jmoto Glad to help. You can mark the question as answered by clicking the green check mark on the left. :)